# Find and Increment a Number in cpp Source

Tags: c++, bash, perl

I'd like to preface that I am unable to make changes to the underlying source code. This is code that gets checked out for each project for a team and I cannot make any changes at this time.

Okay so essentially, in a particular .cpp file, let's say foo.cpp, there is a unique line somewhere in the middle that reads:

```
FT_BAR, 1,
```

where 1 could be any number (but is going to be 1,2,3,4,5... practically never anything higher)...

I'd like to have a Bash or Perl script that allows me to automatically find this number and increase it by one. For what purpose you may ask... well, it would save me precious seconds multiple times per day and spare me a great deal of tedium endured by opening and closing this file to increase this number.

What is the best approach to this problem? I'm sure I will be embarrassed by a ridiculously simple one-line solution or some standard Unix tool that does exactly this, but I've been unable to find this so please forgive me if this is the case.

Comment: Use a regex - since this is for a specifc bit of code (not a general case of finding something), it's very simple to whip up a regex that finds a number between two known symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
perl -pe's/(\d+)/$1+1/e if /FT_BAR, \d+,/' foo.cpp > new.cpp
```

Comment: I'd like to note that out of the suggested solutions, this is the solution that I ended up actually using. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perl has the `e` regex flag for `evaluate`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    s/FT_BAR, (\d+),/"FT_BAR, ".($1+1).","/eg;
    print;
}

__DATA__
FT_BAR, 1,
```

You can turn this into a one liner:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/FT_BAR, (\d+),/"FT_BAR, ".($1+1).","/e;' test_re.txt
```

Comment: What happened to the other post? I suppose that guy deleted it. Anyway he had posted:
    perl -i.bak -ple 'if(/FT_BAR,/){@a=split(","); $a[1]++; s/$_/join(", ",@a,)/e;}' filename.cpp

Comment: That'll probably work, yes. I don't think splitting is really necessary though.

Comment: I did delete it. I noticed it was incorrect (missing a comma). I was using split instead of what Sobrique did and was working on a fix. This post is exactly what I was nearly left with and is a more efficient one-liner :)

Comment: `s/$_/join(", ",@a,)/e` is generally written `$_ = join ', ', @a` (unless `$_` contains regex metacharacters, in which case this won't work anyway)

Comment: The one-liner with the split worked, but yes it was missing the comma... Sobrique's one-liner spits out an error "Can't open perl script "s/FT_BAR, (\d+),/"FT_BAR, ".($1+1).","/eg;": No such file or directory.
Use -S to search $PATH for it."

Comment: That sound like missing the `-e` flag.

Comment: You could save that repetition with `s/FT_BAR, \K(\d+)(?=,)/$1+1/e`. And the `/g` modifier is unnecessary. And I don't know what `-n` *and* `-p` together will do, but you certainly don't need both!

Comment: The `-e` option is missing in your own code, because perl will take `ne` as a parameter for `-i`. So you have written `perl -i'ne' -p '...'`

Comment: Well spotted. I thought tidying it up would help, but missed that :/